# US B1/B2 Visa Travel Restrictions?

Tags: visas, usa, new-zealand-citizens

We are NZ citizens living in Mexico.  We have just today had interviews at the US consulate to get US B1/B2 Visas (and approved) for travel into the US.

In talking with a friend here in Mexico they mentioned that when their son (a Mexican citizen) got his visa they found out after the fact that he was only allowed to travel up to 25 miles into the US.

Is that a limitation on the B1/B2 Visa, and if so what do I have to do to have that extended?

Comment: They must be confusing it with a border crossing card. _As of June 2013, the 25 mile border zone in New Mexico was extended to 55 miles allowing BCC holders entering the United States by land, to travel to the cities of Deming and Las Cruces, New Mexico. The current BCC border zone is within 25 miles of the border in California and Texas_; _within 55 miles of the border in New Mexico; and within 75 miles of the border in Arizona_ (https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1635/~/border-crossing-card---who-can-use-it%3F).

Comment: As NZ citizens, is there a reason you're not traveling under the [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html)? Do you need to stay in the US longer than 90 days?

Comment: @ZachLipton We are residents in Mexico - since the beginning of the year we, and others we know here, have found it tougher to get across the border with just the VWP and on one crossing were advised by the CBP that we should probably get Visas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mexican nationals who reside in Mexico can apply for a [border crossing card](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1635/~/border-crossing-card---who-can-use-it%3F), which allows them to enter the US without a passport, but they must remain within 25 miles of the border (55 miles in New Mexico).  The card also serves asa B-1/B-2 visa when it is presented in combination with a passport, so it is easy to confuse border crossing cards with B-1/B-2 visas.

When a border crossing card holder enters using the card and a passport, there is no restriction on where they can travel, and anyone using a "regular" B-1/B-2 visa, that is, one inserted as a sticker in the passport, is also able to travel freely around the United States after being admitted.

Comment: I think that's it, thanks.  My friend mentioned they had to get a permit to allow their son to travel further - it turns out this is an I-94, and after a bit of research it appears we will need to get this updated also.  A lot of rules and paperwork I wasn't even aware of.

Comment: @Midavalo the I-94 is created *electronically* when you enter the country.  If you fly, the airlines will forward your information and you won't have to do anything.  If you enter by land, you may need to take care of it at the border and you may get a paper I-94 of some description.  After you've entered the US, you can check your I-94 records at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.